How much coolant drip is normal on old car without overflow tank
I recently bought a 1976 Ford TC2 Taunus Turnier with the 1.6 pinto engine. It never came with overflow tank from factory and the small hose attached to the radiator cap filler neck area is not connected to anything on the other end that would normally be connected to an overflow tank if it had one, but since it doesnt have one it just hangs down and drips coolant to the ground directly and the hose im talking about can be seen in the first picture below from a random cortina picture i found on internet. I used to think that it was normal for every old car to drip coolant to the ground when they get hot and when steam is vented through there it just drips down to the ground and that you would top the radiator off occasionally with new coolant. However i read in some other forums that when the coolant level is just right, it should never drip from that hose and that the hose will only drip coolant if it was overfilled and that it will only drip it just enough to have perfect coolant level in the cooling system. My car gets pretty hot under 35 degree celcius summer weather in traffic but never actually overheated, but in those situations there are a couple droplets of coolant dripping from that area as it can be seen in the second picture below just under the headlights you can see coolant which is where that hose is located and drips to that location. In that picture it just dripped once but when parking in my garage it would drip 8-9 times by the time im done parking. So im wondering if it is just normal old car with no overflow tank thing or i should maybe flush my cooling system etc so that it wont drip coolant to the ground from that hose when radiator coolant level is set at perfect level?



Looks like a ford Laser or Cortina  ?

@Criggie its a TC2 Taunus (cortina mk4 in uk and australia etc)

TL:DR Probably not a problem.
Cars before coolant recovery systems simply dump excess coolant overboard.  As the coolant heats up it expands.  The cap keeps the coolant in the system until the release pressure is reached and then allows the excess to escape.  Pressure is needed to raise the boiling point of the coolant by about 10%.  When the engine cools and the coolant contracts, the cap lets air into the system.
The next time the car is driven, the coolant expands again and the cap releases as usual.  Since the air pocket is near the cap, it goes first.  That is why a full cold radiator has a coolant level about an inch below the fill neck. This is why older radiators have a larger top tank.
The air (actually water vapor) released when getting hot condenses in the hose and that's where the drips come from.
This can be changed to a coolant recovery system by adding a reservoir that can handle hot liquids and routing the overflow hose to it.  You also will need to have a radiator cap that has the gasket for coolant recovery.  It has the normal gasket on the pressure stem, and another in the cap that rests on the top lip of the filler neck.  (If you have replaced the cap, it probably does have the gasket).  Older caps will just have a brass spring lip in the cap.
With coolant recovery, as the coolant cools and contracts, it sucks the coolant out of the reservoir and back into the radiator.  The reservoir needs to be about 1/3 full when cold so you don't introduce air back into the radiator.

i see thanks, so if i understood correctly it ll piss out coolant regardless of coolant level even if it is in correct level it ll still piss out some coolant due to venting steam etc. My granddad had 1975 version of same car with same engine and my dad also used it until 1999 and he says he doesnt remember our old taunus also pissing like that so i thought maybe my current one was problematic (1975 version also didnt have overflow tank). But it was also 24 years ago so maybe he just remembers wrong

@TimothyScherer As long as the engine doesn't overheat and the level in the radiator stabilizes (level when cold stops dropping) a few drops may be expected.  Since it is an older car, I would regularly check the level, and note if it is losing coolant.  More than a few drops may indicate a new cap is needed.

I don't really know if it is normal or not, but I don't think it's a good thing. I don't ever remember my older cars dripping coolant, but then again they all had overflow bottles attached. To my knowledge, it shouldn't be dripping as a regular thing. The overflow tube is there for a reason: it allows a path for coolant to flow when the cap relieves pressure. It shouldn't have to do this often.
Will it hurt anything on the car if it isn't overheating? Probably not as long as you keep up with the coolant to ensure it is full up. Realistically, a few drops at a time would take a long time to create a deficit which would impact the cooling.
Some things to consider:

How old is the coolant? If the coolant is old, you may want to consider not only changing it out, but putting a newer style coolant in it which would stand up to the heat better.
Does the radiator cap need changed? If the cap is older or the pressure spring is weakening, it may not be sealing at 100%. A change of radiator cap may be a way to overcome the dripping.
Why not just fit an overflow bottle and call it a day? While it's not a lot of coolant you're losing, consider it dripping on the ground and causing spots on your driveway. Getting an aftermarket reservoir isn't expensive, nor would it be hard to fit.


Examine your radiator cap carefully. It may have a two way valve; pressure relief for overheating above rated pressure, and a vacuum valve. The large rubber gasket and spring is the pressure relief valve. The center large looking washer may be spring loaded closed. When pulling it, another lighter spring allows the cooled coolant to create a vacuum that can collapse hoses if it didn't open to allow air back in. If your radiator cap is a two way cap, mount an overflow container nearby with a longer hose to fit into the bottom. A pint container may be all you need, something like a rubbing alcohol container so you can see fluid accumulation. With a makeshift overflow container, as coolant cools off and a vacuum occurs, the vacuum should draw coolant from the overflow container. Older vehicles never had overflow containers and the rule back then was not filling the radiator to the top, leaving coolant covering the radiator tubes and a airspace above. This allows coolant to expand without being expelled thru the radiator cap. It was later determined to add the overflow tank and fill the radiator without any air space.

Right, I added a bottle to an old Subaru I had to solve this problem. I would think, Oh, the coolant is 2 inches low! add some and it would go right out the next day. It turns out I was just overfilling it, but I was used to cars with an overflow bottle.

Same problem - so I have fitted an overflow bottle to my old `73 landrover.  Sometimes the catcher is empty, and sometimes it has half a litre of coolant inside.
I generally decant the top back into the radiator, but as soon as the flow shows brown instead of green, I stop pouring and rinse the mud out in the garage sink.
Presumably a small amount of sludge is coming out with the boiling overflow.
As for construction, it was an aluminium bottle hanging around the end of the overflow hose, such that it is supported in a cage while being out of the way of the fan and other surrounding items.  Not fancy, but has worked for 15 years now.

your landy also doesnt actually overheat right? im guessing it just pisses a bit like mine but doesnt actually overheat

@TimothyScherer The car's 51 years old, and the holden 202 engine is even older.  I raise a sweat when I work hard, why shouldn't the car do the same?.
